rsyslog not printing emergency logs to the console
I use Ubuntu 24.04 with rsyslogd 8.2312.0.
I am creating a brand new rsyslog server based on Ubuntu 24, and wanted to write it all in RainerScript. I wrote the following:
if ($syslogseverity == 3) then {
    call r_error
    }

ruleset(name="r_error"){
    action(type="omusrmsg" users="*" )
    }

My expectation is that if the server receives a syslog message with severity 3 or lower, all currently logged in users will receive a broadcast message (similar to when using wall command).
Well, it isn't happening. I test it by running the following command:
logger -p local0.err -t test_message "This is a test syslog message" -n 127.0.0.1

I can see the log arriving and being processed by rsyslogd. I also confirmed that my if statement catches it and r_error ruleset gets called, however I do not see any broadcast messages.
What am I doing wrong?

There may be constraints on showing msgs imposed by each terminal. Does wall show msgs? Does wall still show them if it run as the same user as rsyslog, if that is not root? Does mesg typed into a terminal reply is y to say msgs are allowed? Why does logger need the -n option?

When I login as  a normal user and do wall test, I do get the broadcast message. When I test it as syslog user with sudo su -l syslog -s /bin/bash it doesn't work, the message doesn't get printed.

I'm not on ubuntu at the moment, but it seems mesg y does a chmod on the terminal's pty (use tty command to show it) to change the group permissions to write. The group ownership is by group "tty". Perhaps rsyslog needs to run in group root or a login that includes group id "tty"?
